# Remove stop words (tm package)

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from dataset. Even after I have performed operation like removing punctuation, numbers. I still see the word “and”,”for” in the word cloud. Is there a fix to it ?

Below is my code

```
library(tm) 

# Pre Processing
documents <- tm_map(documents, content_transformer(tolower),lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, removePunctuation,lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, removeNumbers,lazy=TRUE)

documents <- tm_map(documents, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
**documents <- tm_map(documents, removeWords,        stopwords("english"),lazy=TRUE)**
documents <- tm_map(documents, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, stemDocument, language = "english",lazy=TRUE)

documents <- tm_map(documents, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, removeWords, stopwords("english"),lazy=TRUE)

#output2 <- as.data.frame(documents)

#View(output2)
reservedM<-c("if","for","function","else","repeat","next","and") 
documents <- tm_map(documents, removeWords, reservedM,lazy=TRUE)
documents <- tm_map(documents, stripWhitespace,lazy=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could the order of your operations be the cause? Stopwords should be removed at the beginning.